# In cassandra SASI custom index, need to change Analyzer class from StandardAnalyzer to NonTokenizingAnalyzer. Does it causes impact on any means?

Tags: indexing, database-design, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

**Which analyzer is costlier over time, disk space , based on search criteria over the data?**

Note: I'm using NonTokenizing Analyzer for the *case-sensitive* feature.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzer_class : Analyzers can be specified that will analyze the text in the specified column.

- The NonTokenizingAnalyzer is used for cases where the text is not
  analyzed, but case normalization or sensitivity is required.
- The StandardAnalyzer is used for analysis that involves stemming, case
  normalization, case sensitivity, skipping common words like "and" and
  "the", and localization of the language used to complete the analysis

So moving from StandardAnalyzer to NonTokenizingAnalyzer you loose the capability of skipping common words, localization, etc. So it really depends on the query that you are trying to solve, determines the switch.

In terms of cost on disk space, StandardAnalyzer does use more as it has to process more, but provides more functionality as well. So it really depends on your use case.

Comment: thanks for the reply@dilsingi. Does it cause any impact on performance point of view while migrating to NonTokeninizing Analyzer ? as mentioned in the following  link [http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058]  it seems long text have some impact on disk space usage  as I'm new to cassandra i don't have any clear idea on this i didn't see any info regarding this in datastax official page.

Comment: As far as Datastax, SASI indexes in DSE are experimental. DataStax does not support SASI indexes for production. So to understand your question better, is the move to NonTokenizingAnalyzer to save disk space and not related to any added functionality?

Comment: To avoid case-sensitivity we are moving to Nontokenizing analyzer and  this is the main use case but I need to  analyse , is there any impact on anyways (disk space, latency etc) while moving to this compared to Standard Analyzer?

Comment: I guess you are confused between functionality and performance. You can’t analyze once you move to NonTokenizing analyzer. So not sure what you are trying to achieve